# Create WCF https server with android client

Tags: android, wcf, encryption, https, certificate

I want to connect a Android client to WCF Webservice. There are several good guides describing how to do this but the https concept is really blurry for me. Here is what i want:

1) A selfhosted WebService communicating over https with an authenticated client.
The user database resides on a SQL Server.
The Service must be a "simple install" for any user to carry out.
The user will install the service on his/her PC and then download the client from google play configuring it using ipadress only.

Problem: it seems impossible to carry out this using WCF cause wshttp looks like having the need to install a certificate on the mashine. 
A possible way forward would be generating a selfsigned cert during install but how can i then in a userfriendly manner get the cert to an android client?

2) A Android app published on Google Play which is able to communicate with the service. Data sent to the service will be both simple datatypes (string and integer data) but also large binaries 3-25Mb.

The user installing the service has no more the knowledge than his ip adress and must not be bothered with any certificate issues or other technical details. One option might be using message instead of transport security but my knowledge is very limited in this area.

Information passed between server and client is of personal caracter and may contain passwords including matching sites where passwords are used, personal info, calendar events etc. It will not contain money transfer orders, credit card numbers or account numbers.

The core functionallity of both server and client are more or less already implemented. I now need to secure communication between client and server.

Any recommendation for a good approach to develop this will be grately appreciated!

Comment: Do you expect a typical user of your Android app to have a Windows pc and willing to install SQL server? What data are you trying to store and why there?

Comment: Yes. The user will perform a hands off install of the service having no interaction with SQL. The SQL will store a couple of 100k+ items which need indexing and will be queried from different perspectives. But that part ia already working :) The big issue i have is to secure communication between android client and server so that clients need to authenticate against the service and perform uploads and downloads in a way which cannot be easily intercepted. The information the service holds needs to be fairly secure and also the information sent between client and server.

Comment: Why don't you offer hosting of this data as a service? It's pretty trivial to generate a certificate upon installation, but I don't know how to approve a self-signed one in Android. I do however foresee a support hell if you're going to install SQL Server on client's PC's, generate and trust a self-signed certificate just to be able to run your app, and finally connecting by IP, which means they can only access it from home given NAT is active in 99,9% of internet connections. I'm really curious what you're building.

Comment: But apart from that: WCF security, generating and approving certs is documented well on the WWW.

Comment: Hosting is not an option cause users will not want to upload gigabytes of data. Approving self-signed in android is done using Bouncy Castle. Support hell for SQL hmm maybe but that will not be the biggest issue i think. Getting users to connect using nat will be a bigger issue.

Comment: After googleing 4 days i cannot really find a good answer... In core i want to secure data on a server and the communication to and from an android client.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which i want to deploy the server service to end users makes it hard to use WCF with ssl.
other options create other problems. i have now abandoned WCF for this specific project in favor to Good old socket programming using Bouncy Castle, SslSocket and a custom protocol. It may me overkill but gives me full control over both authentication certificate management and the data being sent.
Im using ssl with a selfsigned cert and override the cert validation method in android verifying all data in the cert manually except relolving the host name... enough for me since i use a pre shared key to encrypt and decrypt data.

Thanks for all help